# Compute difference of DateTimes from different time zones

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

There are 2 events (start and stop of some job) in the past which happened in different time zones.

I need to compute duration of the job.
I can get difference between those time zones in minutes and compute duration like this:

```
var duration = endTime - startTime.AddMinutes(diff);
```

However, there is a thing which confuses me.
Suppose start event happend in California and end event was in say Israel.
Right now difference between these time zones is 9 hours - California just switched to the day light and Israel not yet.
Next week this difference will be 10 hours because Israel will switch.

So, duration will be different if computed now and on the next week.

What is the right way to compute it?
Use `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: `So, duration will be different if computed now and on the next week.` Is that what you want? If not, what behaviour do you want? Is there a reason you are using local times rather than UTC?

Comment: Always date/time stamp events using UTC/GMT.

Comment: I think you want to look in to using Universal DateTime (UTC).
Basically, keep all non-user DateTime values as UTC DateTimes and only convert to local values when displaying to users in either the UI or in reports or other outputs

Comment: @mjwills No, I don't want different duration. If job lasted 1 hour I should always show 1 hour no matter what is the time difference between those time zones now. I'm receiveing these DateTimes from 3rd party and they are local.

Comment: You will need to convert them to UTC (when you receive them) and store and compare them in UTC. _This will likely be buggy during DST transitions._

Comment: What format are the timestamps in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, duration will be different if computed now and on the next week.

I think you're forgetting that its you who is moving through time. not the project start and end times. therefore results will always be the same.

Id be tempted though just to convert the second time into the zone of the first, so it's just a straight diff. to convert from utc to any other zone you can use the following code

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```

Theres also good info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

Comment: Using this: `var duration = endTime - startTime.AddMinutes(diff)` it probably won't be the same as `diff` will change.

Comment: diff wont change if the dates dont change. When calculating the difference .NET takes into account daylight savings etc, as long as you use the full datetime when making calculations

Comment: Ok, got it - my point of confusion was that I'm getting time zones difference in minutes, not just names of 2 time zones.

Comment: @nitsram - Actually, `DateTime` specifically does *not* take any DST or time zone changes into account.  `TimeZoneInfo` will though, and so will math on `DateTimeOffset`.  But not `DateTime`.

Comment: Correct, when calculating the difference between two datetimes (using the correct methods) time zone can be taken into account. But a datatime does not hold time zone data. Sorry if I was not clear.